# Reverse connections on usb-c hub?

Tags: usb, usb-c, hub

I'm wondering if it's possible to reverse the connections on a regular usb-c hub so that, for instance, I can have a single usb-c cable for all the functionality of a PC.

So for instance, if a raspberry pi has its HDMI and USB-a connected to a hub, can I plug that hub into a monitor to display video from the pi on the monitor as well as use a keyboard and mouse connected to the monitor?

Comment: how would you connect the keyboard and mouse to the monitor?

Comment: @Gantendo: Lots of monitors do have USB ports.

Comment: @Mystara: If i understand correctly, this would not only rely on the hub to process signals the way you intend, but also on the monitor being able to "pipe" the signal inputs of connected USB devices to another USB port using that one as output. I highly doubt this would be possible, but maybe you could just skip the hub-thingy, connect a raspberry to your monitor, connect a mouse to the monitor and see for yourself? Also, mentioning a usb hub, why not connecting mouse and keyboard there?

Comment: @Gantendo: As xph says.  Lots of monitors have USB hubs.

Comment: @xph: The USB side of things does work the way that you've mentioned.  My monitor has a USB plug to a PC as well as the regular USBs.  My question was more directed at the HDMI side of things.  I imagine the usual use-case of the hub would be for the HDMI socket to be used to connect a receiver of an HDMI signal (a monitor).  Here I'm proposing to use it to connect a source of an HDMI signal (the pi) and output that via the usb-c.  I'm not sure whether the hub is smart enough to handle that or if it'll all just be fine due to usb-c negotiation.  My monitor doesn't have HDMI so I cannot check.

Comment: @Mystara: I've never heared of a hub or dock working the way you want to. Doesn't mean it's impossible, just means *i* can't help there. Every hub or dock i came across, doesn't work this way. I have to do with Dell docks and 3rd party docking solutions all the time, wired to a computer using USB-A or USB-C, having mous etc. connected using USB-A and output-monitors using DisplayPort or HDMI, mostly. None of the setups i know would work otherwise. So... good luck!

Comment: @xph Thanks.  Sounds like it might be worth trying just to see what the answer is :)

Answer (score 0):

My HP monitors have the USB extension port - two connectors, one to the PC and the other to something else. I always thought it was a pointless feature.

You can certainly try it.  It should work. Keeping in mind the following points, it should not damage anything.

- But the port is **unlikely to be USB3**.  So, certain devices may not work.
- Also, it is **unlikely to supply much power**, so you have to ensure that you are not plugging in hungry devices such as external HDDs,

Comment: Understood on both points, and thanks for the warning.  But what about the HDMI side of things?  Will the hub be able to output a received HDMI signal to the usb-c port?

Answer (score 0):

It is theoretically possible?  Sure, but there's that old engineering joke about wanting three things (usually something like fast, light, and cheap) but only getting to choose two.  If it is cheap then it is not likely to be safe to use.  If it is safe to use then it is not likely to be cheap.

The way the USB spec is written just getting anything USB-C to safely plug into a USB-A port is not easy.  This is an artifact of the original spec not having any idea that USB-C would be coming along years later.  There are adapters for plugging USB-C devices or cables into USB-A ports but nearly all of them are a ***fire hazard***.  People lost some very expensive hardware because of a very cheap adapter.  As far as I know any fires from such attempts didn't cause any serious damage beyond the computer hardware.  Up to this point in time.

How this would have to work is take the HDMI input and then incorporate that into something the display could understand, while also taking in the USB signal and safely incorporating that too.  If the display understands HDMI over USB-C (which is unlikely) and the only concern is for USB 2.0 speeds (quite possible as most people only use the monitor USB ports for keyboard and mouse) then maybe a compatible adapter cable could be made safe and cheap.

Since most displays use DisplayPort over USB-C the HDMI input would likely need conversion to DisplayPort.  I know DisplayPort to HDMI conversion is done cheaply enough, I don't know how hard it would be to go the other way.  USB-A allows for one "lane" of "super speed" USB data while USB-C allows for two "lanes".  This is not likely too much of an issue in this case if USB 3.x speed is to be preserved as it means one "lane" on USB-C for USB 3.x data and the other "lane" for DisplayPort, which is quite common for USB-C displays to do.  What is likely an expensive thing to do is now the hub/cable/adapter/whatever has to allow for negotiation with the display on which lanes on the USB-C connector carries which kind of data.  If the USB-C cable is flipped then there's a renegotiation that needs to happen.

If by chance you do find some kind of hub that claims to do as you spell out then be very skeptical, it is likely a scam.  Doing this cheaply and safely will depend on some very specific and rare compatibility from the display.  Because most displays are not likely to be compatible with the cheap and safe method then the hub is not likely to be safe, and if it is safe then it will not likely be cheap.

Of the three things I suspect you are looking for in such a product you get to choose only two.  Such is life.

Of course the usual disclaimers apply... Past performance doesn't always reflect future performance, your mileage may vary, etc.